# Can't SQL Server store NULLs in fixed-length columns?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, null, storage

I came across this statement in [the official Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10405_01/appdev.120/e10379/ss_oracle_compared.htm#r22c1-t4):

> In Microsoft SQL Server, only columns with variable-length data types
>   can store NULL values. When you create a column that allows NULLs with
>   a fixed-length data type, the column is automatically converted to a
>   system variable-length data type...

I have never read about this in [the SQL Server docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql) nor have I experienced such a thing. On the contrary: in SQL Server, fixed-length data types (such as int and float, but also char) are heavily used and stored very efficiently even when NULLable.

Is there any rationale behind this Oracle statement?!

Comment: Some info on that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13536831/73226 BTW if you click the "back" icon on your link to go to [the previous page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10405_01/appdev.120/e10379/overview_rptss.htm) it states *Microsoft SQL Server is used in this document to refer to Microsoft SQL Server 6.5, Microsoft SQL Server 7.0, and Microsoft SQL Server 2000 unless otherwise stated.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this [was](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug325.htm) the case for Sybase, which is the ancestor for SQL Server. Unfortunately, I did not find any information as to when this exact change was made, but according to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server) the engine was fully rewritten in SQL Server 2005. As this is not the case for any modern SQL Server edition, you can just ignore this statement.